# Do I need XeLaTeX to compile a file which uses the unicode-math package?

Tags: xetex, unicode-math

I have found some information on Wikipedia concerned with `XeTeX` and the `unicode-math` package. My question is, if I include the `unicode-math` package in my document, is it enough to have LaTeX installed and run the Unix `latex` command on my file, or do I need to have `XeLaTeX` installed as well in order to transform my source file into a .dvi/.ps/.pdf file?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't you have `xetex` and/or `luatex` installed with your TeX distribution already?

Comment: Yes, you need to use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX and so you will only get PDF. You most probably have both XeTeX and LuaTeX installed already, so just execute `xelatex file.tex` or `lualatex file.tex`.

Comment: Well, I haven't typeset LaTeX in quite a long time, and last time I was using `tetex` (by Thomas Esser) which no longer exists, and this did not come with XeTeX or LuaTex. What should I install on Linux, and what should I install on Windows to have these available (given that tetex doesn't support them)? Thanks.

Comment: Also, isn't LUA a scripting language to facilitate OpenGL game programmers to write code? What does LUA have to do with LaTeX? I've read the Wikipedia article on `luatex` but things are still not clear to me. Thanks.

Comment: There's [MikTeX](http://miktex.org) for Windows, and [TeXLive](https://www.tug.org/texlive/) for every platform.

Comment: Yeah, I remember `MikTeX`, it dates back to the days of `tetex` even though I never used the former. But `TeXLive` contains really everything, right? So, it would be in my best interest to install TeXLive instead of MikTex, unless I want to save some space? Would this observation be correct?

Comment: @John: You might want to go instead to our chat room to ask these kinds of questions instead of using the comments section (by the way, your OP question is answered literally by just looking at the pop-up of the tag-link [tag:unicode-math], just noticed that `;-)`)

Comment: We have several questions about modern TeX engines, TeX systems and the like. While the question here is not I guess directly addressed by them, the subsequent stuff in comments almost certainly is.

Answer (score 3):

You can't run documents using `unicode-math` with the legacy `latex`. The only possibility is with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, that are included in any recent TeX distribution.